# Assign and remove click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize in advance for my english...

I'm creating an editable table's cell. In this table, I want to remove the click event on the cell (td) clicked but let clickable the other cells.

```
$("#idTable").on("click", "td", function (e) {

    var oTxtbox = $('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
    $(this).html(oTxtbox);

    // I try to remove the event 
    $(this).off(e);

    // $("#idTable").off("click", $(this) );

    // other code

});
```

With the statement `$(this).off(e)` I remove the event of all cells, instead 
`$("#idTable").off("click", $(this) )` I don't remove anything: all cells are clickable.

Can you help me?

UPDATE 1:
This is a demo of my example: [EXAMPLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/19/)

**UPDATE 2:**
Now I have another problem with the events: If user click outside the table I want to re-bind/re-attach the event on td. This is a link with a complete code: [NO RE-BIND EVENT](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/38/)

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Regarding updated2: As you are using the apprach suggested in this accepted answer in which you don't unbind the events but only stop propagation you are now heading torwards a solution which causes you to end up with multiple events being attached everywhere. This could end up with multiple events firing doing the same thing, adding ultiple textboxes and end up in a memory issue if not done carefully. You current code you linked in the update 2 has several issues. You bind click to document everytime a row is double clicked. See this for the issue:http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/39/

Comment: Bascially, your console output shows you how many click events are attached to the document. Double-Click all 3 rows in a row and you see events piling on in the console output. This is only one issue, you are going to have. Use `off().on()` everytime you bind in your case, specially if you intend to re-bind. Add your outer table binding into a separate method which you call ones at the start and then again each time you wish to re-bind. Your document binding is going to be tricky. Each td click = document click! See this for more console outputs http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/40/

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: thanks again! Now it's work. Are there still several issues in my code? Also the keypress event should take out?[link](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/42/)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I answer myself alone: also keypress must go outside. This is a link to new code [NEW CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/43/). Now the code is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `$(this)` is what you think it is.  It is the matching `<td>`, which is not where the event is caught (it is caught on the `$("#idTable")` when it bubbles up.

Replacing the `.off` lines with this line inside your handler will do what you want:

```
$this.on('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();} );
```

Comment: @Webman: It is correct, the event is bubbled up to the table, that is why I had such a hard time to unbind the individual elements. I have since worked out how to work around this and truly unbind the event from the element ones clicked using `one()`. Though the above answer stops a second bound click event on the element from propagating it still has always an event which executes instead of the event being truly unbound from the element.

Comment: @SteveCampbell: +1 for a nice solution.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, you are right - it is less than ideal.  A better solution would be to add or remove a class on the td to cause it to be removed the live event handler.  Here is an example that does that: http://jsfiddle.net/H2cmA/

Comment: @SteveCampbell: Though this prevents the click event from being associated to the correct element now you still have an event attached to the table. Same as having a click event with propagation being stopped attached to the `td` in your answer. If you switch to Jquery 1.7.2 in the fiddle and add `console.log($('#mytable').data('events'));` (command is removed in 1.8) just after the class removal, you can see the event still exists and will be in "limbo". I tried to find a way to completely remove of the actual event binding instead of disassociation.

Comment: @SteveCampbell: Don't get me wrong, I really think your answer is great and it does work. Hence the +1 :)

Comment: Another question: Why the only `e.stopPropagation()` don't work? Why do I write `$this.on('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();} );
`?

Comment: @Webman: Steve is adding a new click event to the `td` which is using `stopPropagation` to prevent the click event from being bubbled up, thus preventing the click event bound to the `#table` for that `td` from being reached. If you simply would call `e.stopPropagation` inside your dynamic click all other `td` elements you click on would stop working too even if not yet clicked.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: thanks so much. Do you know something about the problem of UPDATE 2 in my original message?

Comment: @Webman: See my comments regarding update 2 on your original question. You are going to have to add a few `console.log($("element").data("events"))` checks to your code or you end up with a memory leak. I would recommend to use a solution which always unbinds everything when it is not required anymore, hence `one()`. Also if you plan on re-binding, use `off().on()` or `off().one()`. Be carefully with events attached which simply stop propagation as they are still events which execute up to that point and having them pile on top of each other when  using `on()` is not good for memory either.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

*I just seen you found a solution, sweet :).*

*For completeness though I leave my answer as I finally found how to unbind the events completely.*

> You are using dynamic bindings and as such unbinding an individual element is
>   quite complex due to the event always bubbling up to the static element
>   it is bound from.
>
> As seen in the other answer, you can overwrite the click event with a
>   new click event and stop propagation.
>
> **However**, that still leaves you with an element which has an event
>   attached which always executes when clicked, even if it doesn't bubble
>   up.

The example below truly unbinds the event, leaving you with no left-over and not requiring propagation being stopped as the event is completely unbound:

```
$(document).one('click', 'div', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find("div").one('click.NewClick', function() {
        $('#result').append(this.id + " was clicked<br />");
    });

    $(this).click();
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9YXUC/) - Unbinding individual elements bound dynamically

In the above demo I'm using [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) through-out to ensure automatic unbinding of the event.

The outer `one()` is required for the logic, the inner `one()` is your requirement as you wanted the event unbound ones clicked.

I'm binding the initial `click` event as usual with the dynamic selector 'div', using `one()`.

However, ones I'm inside the `click` event, after any of the divs have been clicked, I'm re-binding the click event to the elements, using `one()` again, this time using the `static` selector though as the elements now exists. I'm also using a namespace `'click.namespace'` to ensure the unbinding of the outer `one()` does not get rid of the new bindings.

Now I have all my divs nicely bound with `one()`, which means they automatically unbind completely after being clicked.

To prevent the user from having to click twice after the initial click, I'm automatically triggering the click event (`$(this).click()`) of the element which was triggered the initial event, making is seamless to the user.

Your code should be able to use this with code similar to the below:

```
$("#idTable").one("click", "td", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find("td").one('click.NewClick', function() {
        var oTxtbox = $('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
        $(this).html(oTxtbox);

        // other code
    });

    $(this).click();
});​
```

Note the use of **one()**, instead of **on()**.
Off course the inner binding can be what ever you need it to be, `one()` was only selected as you wanted the event unbound after the element was clicked.

Comment: I have also tried $(this).off("click") but nothing. I will try with "one"

Comment: @Webman: I only noticed earlier you are binding to dynamic events. When binding to dynamic events unbinding individual elements seem to be a pain. I will update you in a second.

Comment: @Webman: Please see the edit how truly to unbind the event from the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `unbind` ?

```
$("#idTable").on("click", "td", function (e) {
  var item=$(this);

  var oTxtbox = $('<input type="text" value="' + item.text() + '"/>');
  item.html(oTxtbox);

  item.unbind("click")

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

> Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

**EDIT :** When we need to remove a handler from itself, we need to do this approach.

So the code should be

```
$("#idTable").on("click", "td", function (e) {
  var item=$(this);

  var oTxtbox = $('<input type="text" value="' + item.text() + '"/>');
  item.html(oTxtbox);

  item.unbind(e)

});
```

> The handler in this case must take a parameter, so that we can capture
>   the event object and use it to unbind the handler after the third
>   click. The event object contains the context necessary for .unbind()
>   to know which handler to remove.

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/24/

Comment: In that way the other td are not editable. Example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tRNhJ/27/)